# How do I execute a method while displaying a ProgressBar, then show a Form after?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, progress-bar

How do I execute a method while displaying a ProgressBar, then show a Form after?

```
private void btnCienciaEmissao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progressForm = new ProgressBar.frmPBText();
    var retornoManifestacao = new frmConsultaNotaEmitidaContraCNPJAntigoRetornoManifestacao();

    var threadProcesso = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Parametros.DgvRetornoManifestacao = ExecutaManifestacao();
            progressForm.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { progressForm.Close(); }));
            retornoManifestacao.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { retornoManifestacao.dgvRetornoManifestacaoDataSource(Parametros.DgvRetornoManifestacao);}));
        });

    threadProcesso.Start();

    progressForm.Show();

    // I WANT TO SHOW RetornoManifestacao ONLY AFTER threadProcesso FINISHED
    retornoManifestacao.Show();
}
```

I want the Form `retornoManifestacao` to show *after* `threadProcesso` is finished.

If I use `retornoManifestacao.Show()`, like above, the form will appear before `threadProcesso` end. I need it to appear only after the Thread end.

I tried using `threadProcesso.Join()`, but `progressForm` froze.

My `progressForm` has a Marquee Style `ProgressBar`, so it's not necessary to report progress.

Comment: actually very easy to do ..perhaps you should do a google search on how to create a splash screen and or show a progress Bar before showing a form..

Comment: @GrantWinney If I use RetornoManifestacao.Show(), like above, the form will appear before threadProcesso end. I need it to appear only after the Thread end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to move the call to `Show()` into your thread so that it's executed as the last thing the thread does. For example:

```
private void btnCienciaEmissao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progressForm = new ProgressBar.frmPBText();
    var retornoManifestacao = new frmConsultaNotaEmitidaContraCNPJAntigoRetornoManifestacao();

    var threadProcesso = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Parametros.DgvRetornoManifestacao = ExecutaManifestacao();
            progressForm.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                // These can (and should) all go in a single invoked method
                progressForm.Close();
                retornoManifestacao.dgvRetornoManifestacaoDataSource(Parametros.DgvRetornoManifestacao);
                retornoManifestacao.Show();
            }));
        });

    threadProcesso.Start();

    progressForm.Show();
}
```

That said, if you are using .NET 4.5, it seems to me a somewhat different approach overall would work better:

```
private async void btnCienciaEmissao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progressForm = new ProgressBar.frmPBText();

    progressForm.Show();
    Parametros.DgvRetornoManifestacao = await Task.Run(() => ExecutaManifestacao());
    progressForm.Close();

    var retornoManifestacao = new frmConsultaNotaEmitidaContraCNPJAntigoRetornoManifestacao();

    retornoManifestacao.dgvRetornoManifestacaoDataSource(Parametros.DgvRetornoManifestacao);
    retornoManifestacao.Show();
}
```